# Change the size of CardLayout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I am unable to align the gridpanels in Swing because of fixed size of CardLayout.

I have a gridPanel gpTenderTypes for which i have used the Card Layout.

```
 gpTenderTypes.setLayout(new CardLayout());
```

When a button is clicked, the card will change and the class will be called (for example, when creditcard button is clicked, creditcard card in the grid panel will be shown and the Card1() object will be called.

```
gpTenderTypes.add(new Cash1(), DBConstants.TENDER_TYPE_CASH);
gpTenderTypes.add(new Card1(), DBConstants.TENDER_TYPE_CREDIT_CARD);
```

gpTenderTypes is added in another gridPanel gp2row along with 2 other gridpanels.

```
gp2row.addFilledComponent(gpCustDet, 1, 1, 6, 1,GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
gp2row.addFilledComponent(gpTT, 1, 7, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);        
gp2row.addFilledComponent(gpButtonsPanel, 1, 8, 6, 1,GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
```

gp2row is added in the screen:

```
this.addFilledComponent(gp2row, 2, 1, 14, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
```

I've realized that the size of the CardLayout remains constant  irrespective of changing its size using setSize or setPreferredSize. Changing the dimensions of the other GridPanels (gpCustDet, gpButtonsPanel) is of no use either.

How do i do fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Please post mode code (SSCCE)

Answer (score 0):

The size of the `CardLayout` (really the size of the Component whose layout is the `CardLayout`) is not defined by anything you do to the children of that component, but rather by the component itself and its parent component and its parent's layout manager.  Without some more detail in your code we can't be sure but I would look there first.